# Causal models in pymc3

Tags: bayesian, bayesian-network, pymc

I'm trying to fit a causal model. Participants in a task are trained on the model then asked for their belief in all the joints over the variables (e.g., what are the chances of observing an item with `cause_1` and `effect` present and `cause_2` absent?)

I want to infer people's beliefs in the strengths of two causes, as well as various other beliefs (background causes of the effect, likelihood of the causes, etc.). This is a very simplistic model to get my toes wet.

My specification is as follows:

```
# Common effect model with 2 causes (c1 and c2) causing an effect e.
# Causes combine using a 'noisy or' rule: two causes independently bring about the effect with probability m.
# r is the likelihood of the causes.
# bg is the probability of the effect coming about without a cause.

ncauses = 2
nvars = ncauses + 1

joints = np.array([[c1, c2, e] for c1 in [0, 1] for c2 in [0, 1] for e in [0, 1]])
resps = (np.array([10.0, 1.0, 3.0, 10.0, 4.0, 10.0, 4.0, 11.0])-1)/10 # converting from their 11-point scale.


def noisy_or(r, m, bg):
    pc = switch(joints[:,:-1], r, 1-r)
    pe_absent = (1-bg) * prod(1-r*m)
    pe = switch(joints[:,-1], 1-pe_absent, pe_absent)
    return prod(pc, axis=1) * pe

def beta_recoded(name, ratio, confidence, **kwargs):
    beta = confidence / (ratio+1)
    alpha = confidence - beta
    return Beta(name, alpha=alpha, beta=beta, **kwargs)

with Model() as model:
    r = Beta('r', alpha=1, beta=1, shape=(1, ncauses))
    m = Beta('m', alpha=1, beta=1, shape=(1, ncauses))
    bg = Beta('bg', alpha=1, beta=1)
    pjoints = noisy_or(r, m, bg)
    ratings = beta_recoded('ratings', pjoints, 5, observed=resps)
```

With this setup, find_MAP chokes. Did I do things reasonably? One of the weird things is that when calculating the probability of each of the joints, there's a sort of if-then structure (if var is absent, we want 1-p, else p) which I turned into abs(is_absent-p), I wasn't sure what was the most elegant way to do that. EDIT: this has been fixed using switch.

EDIT: `pymc3` appears to require the development version of Theano in git.

Comment: Can you post the error which you get? How does MAP choke?

Comment: The most elegant way to do the if then structure is going to be theano's switch(condition, if_true, if_false) function. http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#tensor.switch

Comment: That looks like a theano issue to me. Theano is trying to find the gradient and choking